# requirejs not loading other scripts in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, requirejs

I have a site that uses require.js (www.easyzag.com). It is working great on chrome/FF but in IE it isn't loading any of my script files.

I tried using the IE9 dev tools but couldn't seem to find much. It enters the require file but once that is done running there are no other script files linked in the dev tools.

There are no errors or anything being printed to the console.

Any ideas on what i should check out or what i may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 9 Has trouble with *setting* non-standard attributes. You do so here, in the header of your page:

```
...
script.setAttribute("data-main", "js/main");
...
```

You should place the tag in plain HTML in your header, with the `data-main` attribute specified.

Comment: awesome, Yeah that works now. Only problem I am having now is that the reason i had dynamically created the script tag was to ensure that the FB.getLoginStatus had already run. Is there any way to still achieve this?

Comment: Ah, I noticed that after I posted this answer. You could place the empty tag with just the `data-main` attribute, and then edit its `src` using `setAttribute` in that FB callback. I would recommend integrating the FB API into your require app, though.

Comment: I am integrating it in the next version, but i need to hotfix it for IE right now so am looking for 'hacky' ways to do it temporarily. Thanks for the tip

Comment: it doesn't look like setting source makes it run.. but maybe im doing something wrong

Comment: i still have this issue in 2015. Any resolution? In my case I can see requirejs loading but then the script from data-main is not loaded at all. I'm using require 2.1.17